# gnome system monitor for solaris

Tags: solaris

is there any gui tools like gnome system monitor in solaris for monitoring processes? or is it possible to get the gnome system monitor binary pkg for solaris os ?

Comment: belongs on superuser.com or serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify which version of Solaris - recent ones include gnome-system-monitor already.
Additional gnome software for older Solaris versions may be available from various projects that make open source software packages available for Solaris, such as [SunFreeware](http://www.sunfreeware.com/), [Blastwave](http://www.blastwave.org/), and [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/)

The CDE desktop included in Solaris 2.6 through Solaris 10 also includes a couple of simpler process monitoring tools - [sdtprocess](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/806-4743/processmanagerusing-23/index.html) and [sdtperfmeter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/806-4743/perfmeterusing-64/index.html).

Comment: The OS version is 5.10.. But I can't find gnome sysmon for 5.10 in sunfreeware , blastwave or opencsw... I installed gnome sys mon using pkg-get but when I run binary . It says "Can only run on SunOS 5.8 sun4u \n glibtop: Requested 52 bytes but got 4256701908." Is there a way to get same package for 5.10? I searched in google i couldn't find one

Answer (score 0):

How about [GKrellm](http://www.optix.org/~dxy/solaris/gkrellm/)? That is popular under the Gnome suite running on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind me asking what is the need for a gui?

the command top will give you everything you need but in a terminal?!?

anyway /usr/dt/bin/sdtperfmeter is on older releases but this WONT give you processes

gnome-system-monitor should be installed on newer releases, and this WILL give you processes.

If the gnome-system-monitor command doesn't work top will.